# How to login as a newly created customer in Jira service desk

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am very new to Jira REST API, I am trying to create a customer in Jira service Desk and followed the documentation [Jira Documentation Rest API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-servicedesk/REST/3.6.1/#servicedeskapi/servicedesk/%7BserviceDeskId%7D/customer-addCustomers), and I was successfully able to

- create a customer through REST API
- Add customer to a particular Service Desk
- Add Customer to an Organization

Now, I want a way to send an email about the **login details and login URL** to the newly created customer's e-mail or at-least where are the login credentials saved about the newly created customer, I can may be find a way to email in some other way. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know your use case, but maybe a free login portal can work for you:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/servicedeskcloud/blog/2017/04/introducing-the-login-free-portal-for-jira-service-desk-cloud